#  Misleading message when trying to downvote with too little reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, down-votes

I don't yet have enough rep on Area51 to downvote. But when I tried to downvote [a question in an Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34674/czech-language-usage/34700#34700), I got the following message:

[image: Voting a question up requires 50 reputation]

Note that I was trying to vote down, not up. Also, I have more than 50 reputation on Area51, making the message even more confusing.

Comment: Change it to: "Don't even *try* voting anything down yet."

Comment: That message should pull the number from http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-question-down, and not offer methods to earn the rep.

Comment: I just got 100 rep overnight. I guess a recalculation happened that gave me a forgotten bonus – my Area51 account got merged with my main Stack Exchange account recently, after I had some trouble with adding the openID login, and I have enough rep on SO to get 100 rep on other sites. So now I have more than 150 and can downvote normally. Perhaps this bug only happens when the account is in such a weird state...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks for the report.

I should have caught this bug – it's a result of the fact that in the old (pre-October) A51 voting scheme, great-on-topic-example and great-off-topic-example used the same error message, whereas now, up-vote and down-vote require different error messages.